# Create users without a password in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have three user roles defined using enums and a single users table with STI. My three user roles are staff, clinician, and listed. The aim is that staff will upload lists of names and emails which will create users of role listed. Once these listed users create their own passwords, their role will change to clinician.

I am working on adjusting my model and controller to allow to create these listed users but running into difficulty as most of the answers I've found deal with a Devise implementation. I am using an authentication system mostly built with Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial. Do you have any tips on how I can get this to work? Currently when I try to sign up as a listed user, I get the following error:

unknown attribute 'password' for Listed.

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here are my user models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = :role
  enum role: { Staff: 0, Clinician: 1, Listed: 2 }


  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :role, presence: true


  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
        return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end


  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

    # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_attribute(:activated,    true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

 # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

   # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

 def feed
    ReferralRequest.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end


 private

    # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
    end

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end


end


class Staff < User
  validates :university_id, presence: true
  belongs_to :university
  has_many :referral_requests
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
end

class Clinician < User
  has_many :lists
  has_many :universities, through: :lists
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
end

class Listed < User
  has_many :lists
  has_many :universities, through: :lists
end
```

Here is my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:show, :index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

   def show

    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @referral_requests = @user.referral_requests.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User deleted"
  redirect_to users_url
end

    private

        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :role, :university_id, :password, :password_confirmation)

  end

    # Before filters


    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if STI is the best approach to manage roles, anyway, if your `User` class has the attribute `password` and you are correctly making the inheritance, `Listed` should have that attribute too.

Your `Listed` model should look like this:

```
Class Listed < User
end
```

Same for all your models that inherit from User

Comment: What would you recommend as a better approach for roles?

Comment: You can use a different model `Role` with a many to many relationship with User or use a library like Rolify https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify

Comment: Thanks - what advantages do those have compared to using enums and STI?

Comment: Basically, you'll have a better architecture. It's more flexible and you'll be able of assigning more than one role to a user, in case you need it in a future. Also, STI is more suitable when the inherited models could have different attributes than the parent class not different values for one attribute. In your case, I think that it only adds complexity.